# Make sub ul and li inline

Tags: css

I'm developing a navigation menu. There I'm adding a second sub menu. So I couldn't get the second sub menu  inline with the sub-menu

My code is just in jsfiddle to make u guys understand easy. I know its a bit of CSS change. But I didnt find the solution yet. Can anyone give me a suggestion please.

here is my code

```
    <ul>
    <li>item one</li>
    <li style="display:inline-block;">item two two two two two
        <ul>

            <li>Item sub</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>item three three</li>
</ul>
```

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/BWZfr/223/)

Comment: You forgot to add jQuery code in the fiddle.

Comment: Im just fine with jquery.. I want to make that sub <ul> in same line with CSS

Comment: wow 226 edits to that fiddle!

Comment: Does this work at all? http://jsfiddle.net/BWZfr/231/ or http://jsfiddle.net/BWZfr/232/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is this what youre looking for?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BWZfr/233/)

remove `clear: left` from the secondary uls and add `display:inline-block` to the main lis.

also add span elements to wrap the text and float them left so the secondary ul li elements ca float on the same line.

Comment: No..Thats not what im expecting..I dont need to inline main <li> links..I just want to inline the sub <ul> (Item sub) with (item two two two two two) <li>

Comment: @dit1679 whoops put the wrong fiddle link in there.  Now see updated answer.

Comment: That what I needed..I tried in many ways.. Finally thanks tons